# Unable to disable and enable LayoutTransition

Tags: android, android-listview

On my `ListView` I have setup `LayoutTransition` via `onCreate()`. However after transition end I want to disable the transition effect so I set it to **null** in `endTransition()`. So, the problem is after I set it to null I can't event let in enable again when I want to refresh the ListView (I want to disable animation change effect via on scroll, click, drag, expandable)

Here is my code

**MainActivity.class**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      setupListViewAnimation();

 }

 void setupListViewAnimation() {
        if (lt == null) {
            lt = new LayoutTransition();
            lt.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
            lt.addTransitionListener(new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {

                }

                @Override
                public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
                    list.setLayoutTransition(null);
                }
            });
        }
        list.setLayoutTransition(lt);

}


void onClick() {
   //before start to refresh listview
   setupListViewAnimation();

   //refresh listview
   ..............................
   ListView Refresh Logic Here...
   ..............................


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION**

I found my own answer. If I want to disable my `LayoutTransition` Animation instaed of set value to null I can disable it in `endTransition` under `LayoutTransition.TransitionListener()` like below fixed from question

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      setupListViewAnimation();

 }

 void setupListViewAnimation() {
        if (lt == null) {
            lt = new LayoutTransition();
            lt.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
            lt.addTransitionListener(new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {

                }

                @Override
                public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
                     //Change this line of code to below one
                     transition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
                }
            });
        }
        list.setLayoutTransition(lt);

}


void onClick() {
   //before start to refresh listview
   setupListViewAnimation();

   //refresh listview
   ..............................
   ListView Refresh Logic Here...
   ..............................


}
```